# Boundary Matchers Regular Expressions

Tags: java, regex

Why is this false in Java?

```
Pattern.matches("\\A[/0-9]","2 z CEA|B2 z E^")
```

edit:
I tried: (so that I can also catch new lines)

```
Pattern.matches("\\A[/0-9][.\\s]*?","2 z\n CEA|B2 z E^)
```

but it doesn't work. How can I catch something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `.matches()` compares against the entire string, so the pattern must match it.  Try this:

```
Pattern.matches("\\A[/0-9].*?","2 z CEA|B2 z E^")
```

The `.*?` allows for more stuff to be at the end of the line.  Using `*?` for the quantifier makes it select the minimum amount of characters.

Comment: How can I include new lines?
I tried `"\\A[/0-9][.\\s]*?"` but it didn't work

Comment: By default, the . class matches everything besides newlines.  You can include a `(?s)` at the beginning of the regex to put matching into "single line mode", where . does match line ending characters.  `(?s)"\\A[/0-9].*?"`.  Special characters work different in [] sections, they are just characters... not special.  The class `[.\\s]` means match, '.', '\', or 's'.

Answer (score 3):

Because in Java, the `matches` method tries to match the entire string. You need `find` instead:

```
Pattern.compile("\\A[/0-9]").matcher("2 z CEA|B2 z E^").find()
```

(See [the Javadoc for `Pattern.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29), [the Javadoc for `Matcher.matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29), and [the Javadoc for `Matcher.find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29).)

Answer (score 1):

It matches only the first number 2 and not the entire string and so it is false